# Convergent Sequence with Limit Superior

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have been working ahead in my textbook, and came across this question at the end of the questions of the chapter, but there is no explanation of limit superior in the chapter. If someone could please help me with this intriguing question.

[image]

Comment: Note also that there is a subsequence of $x_n$ which tends to $\limsup x_n$. And for every subsequence which converges to $L$, we have $L\leq \limsup x_n$. So $\limsup x_n$ is the greatest (possibly infinite) limit of all convergent subsequences of $x_n$.

Comment: To add to julien's observation, this proves that *every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence*.

Comment: My problem with the question is my textbook does not explain what the lim sup actually means.

Comment: What do you mean? What you gave above defines the limsup as the limit of $y_n$. It is pretty well defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that (1) $y_n$ is decreasing and (2) $y_n$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $\{y_n\}$ is non-increasing and bounded below.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sequence {$x_{n}$} 
Supremum of the terms $x_{n}$,$x_{n+1}$,$x_{n+2}$,$x_{n+3}$,... is denoted by $S_{n}$.
Limit $S_{n}$ is called limitsuperior of $x_{n}$.
For example consider a sequence 100,100,100,1,$\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{1}{4}$,$\frac{1}{5}$,....

$S_{1} =S_{2}=S_{3}$ =100
$S_{4}=1 $
$S_{5}=\frac{1}{2}$.
In particular $S_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \geq 4$ Hence limit $S_{n}$ as $n$ tends to infinity is 0.
In a similar way you can find examples for limit inferior.